# What is the title of this book, whose title had something to do with measurement and a number, and civilization is in a geometric shape?

Tags: story-identification

I  can't remember the title of a book. I think the title has something to do with a measurement of temperature and a number. Possibly  something about kelper??

The plot is about astronauts who go to another planet. They do something to make themselves small (?)  Or in some way are able to interact with the intellect life on the planet, who are very small.

The civilization there is built in some geometric  shape (hexagon?)

I think the leader is a queen, like a queen bee type figure.

Anyway, it turns out that the planet is a bomb, I think a nuclear bomb and all the "workers" were working to prepare it for detonation. It does blow up the planet  and civilization at the end.

I read this book over 10 years ago and have been searching for the title for several years now. May possibly have been written in the 1980s. English language. Any thoughts out there?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is ["Camelot 30K"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camelot_30K) by Robert L. Forward.

The astronauts do not make themselves small, but rather build a small probe in the shape of one of the locals.

> Out on the far boundaries of the Solar System, in the Oort Cloud, intelligent life has been discovered by humanity's space probes. Now the first humans to venture beyond the planetary system have been sent to make contact with this incredibly strange race and to tour the center of their civilization. What they discover is explosive beyond their wildest dreams.

The aliens call themselves *kerack* and the humans give them names from Arthur's cycle: the main alien character is *Merlene*, another is *Launcelot*. Queen Une's bodyguard is called *Mordet*, and the city-state is called *Camalor*.

The kerack spend their time battling with the neighbour cities so that the bravest souls may *descend* to Heaven. Heaven is a great chamber under the Queen's palace, and their souls are little round heavy pellets of uranium - because the kerack have a bio-nuclear biology allowing them to thrive at a mere 30 Kelvin, near absolute zero. Their one great racial achievement is the construction of Heaven, a carefully built semispherical chamber that, not accidentally, acts as a perfect neutron reflector. It is said that when enough souls have descended into Heaven, Camalor will ascend to greatness on a pillar of fire.

This is the scene of the explosion (and I found the reference to the hexagons, which I think is the only one in the book):

> ...stored under the altar, resulting in a large thermonuclear fusion explosion.
>
> Surrounding the explosion was a thick cylinder of lead, surrounded in turn by the heavy metal contents of the privies. The inertia of this thick cylindrical  wall of heavy metals constrained the explosion and directed the explosive force upward, where it struck the under-surface of the Palace o' Princesses under the Plaza o'Dance.
>
> The Palace o Princesses had been fabricated of seamless black boron carbide, which was almost as strong as crystalline diamond and could withstand higher temperatures. The rooms in the Palace o'Princesses had been made hexagonal in shape, producing a structure that had the greatest strength for the least weight. As a result, the Palace o'Princesses maintained its physical integrity as the shock front of the thermonuclear explosion hit it.
>
> The palace accelerated rapidly upward, driven by the directed thermonuclear explosion, until it and the cargo of spores on its upper surface attained escape velocity and were thrown into interstellar space.
>
> "Faster, Hiroshi! Faster!"
>
> Elizabeth was watching the view from the monitor camera on the pole overlooking the plaza. "The princesses have stopped bringing uranium pellets to the Queen and are sliding the doors back into place. Now I know why the doors had to be so massive."
>
> Spurts of yellowish smoke shot from cracks around the loos, and a heartbeat later, the plaza floor rose as a single body carrying with it the piles of spores on its upper surface. There was a blinding flash of light, and the camera monitor over the plaza stopped working.

(Yes, yes. But as Robert L. Forward himself wrote in the preface, *never lets the fact get in the way of a good story*. This book required four or five times my usual level of suspension of disbelief, and I can only say that it was worth it).

## The thermonuclear device

[image: The Palace o'Princesses from Camelot 30K]

Comment: Thank you that is it! Years of searching and after a couple of hours of posting on this site and I  have the answer!

Comment: Still, it should be nuclear *fission* rather than fusion, shouldn’t it?

Comment: @Holger: it is a "fizzle fission triggered fusion explosion". The author supplies the blueprints for the device :-)

Comment: Humans seriously considered nuclear explosion based space travel: [Project Orion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion))

Comment: @Holger I managed a scan of a page from the paper book, with the Palace o'Princesses and its weapon equivalent

Comment: @Holger: Thermonuclear bombs (H-bombs) are fusion bombs, not fission bombs. That's how they are different from (and much stronger than) nuclear bombs (A-bombs). They use a fission explosion to start the fusion explosion.

Comment: @kundor: sure, but the answer didn’t talk about H-bombs, but only “pellets of uranium” when I made the comment. Only after the insertion of the picture, it’s becoming clear where the fusion happens.

Comment: "a small probe in the shape of a local" => "local" is either a typo or a colloquialism with which I'm not familiar. Is there a more common (or less regional) term for what you're talking about?

Comment: @shoover: I interpreted it as the probe being shaped like one of the aliens being studied.

Comment: Ah! A local, as in a local [resident]. OK, perfectly colloquial in my dialect, too. I usually encounter it in the plural, e.g. "in the shape of one of the locals", which is why it didn't click.